# ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python' and I can't install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

**When I try to install tensorflow I get this error:**

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\cauzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\com_github_grpc_grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q59sc.png)

**I updated the pip module:**

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

But then I can't install tensoflow:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\cauzo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\include\external\com_github_grpc_grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths

Comment: Maybe the hint `HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled.` could be helpful.

Comment: I suggest you use anaconda to handle your packages, its much better.